# Passing object to an event

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm learning java at the moment, and I am developing a plugin for Bukkit. Here is my problem:

I have an event that triggers on player clicking the inventory (The event is registered in the Main class):

Register method

```
private void registerEvents() {

    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new SendMailInventory(), this);
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MailInventory(), this);

}
```

onEnable():

```
public void onEnable() {
    Logger log = getLogger();
    PluginDescriptionFile file = this.getDescription();
    log.info(file.getName() + " Version: " + file.getVersion()  + " has been enabled!");
    plugin = this;
    registerCommands();
    registerEvents(); //here
    setConfig();


}
```

When the player uses the command " /smi open " I create a new object that opens the inventory and manages it. 
My problem comes here , I need a way to use the object only for that player to store items , etc...
Like make an instance of the object for every player that uses the command and use the created  object  to do stuff:

Player a --> has his own object from the class pagination

Player b --> has his own object from the class pagination

Player c --> has his own object from the class pagination

etc....

So how could I pass this object to the class where the event is firing? I did this(but I dont think it is the best way , I don't really know):

```
if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("open")) {

    Pagination pag = new Pagination(player);
    MailInventory.pagList.put(player, pag);
    pag.setUpInventories();

    return true;
}
```

So this way from the event class i can do this:

```
@EventHandler
public void clickCrate(InventoryClickEvent e) {

    Player player = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
    Pagination pag = pagList.get(player); //RIGHT HERE

    if(!(e.getInventory().getHolder() instanceof Pagination)) {return;}
    ItemStack itemInHand = e.getCurrentItem();

    if(itemInHand!=null) {
        if(itemInHand.getType().equals(Material.CHEST)) {

            ItemMeta meta = itemInHand.getItemMeta();
            int id = meta.getCustomModelData();
            pag.getItemsFromCrate(id);

        }
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }

}
```

Pagination acts as an InventoryHolder

Answer (score 0):

Im use this class, it allows you to add any items and action on their click

```
public class GUI implements InventoryHolder {

    static {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Listener() {
            @EventHandler
            public void onClick(InventoryClickEvent e) {
                if (e.getInventory().getHolder() instanceof GUI) {
                    ((GUI) e.getInventory().getHolder()).onInventoryClick(e);
                }
            }

        }, Plugin.getInstance());
    }

    private final Inventory inv;
    private final Map<Integer, InventoryAction> runnableMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void open(Player player) {
        Utils.runSyncTask(() -> player.openInventory(getInventory()));
    }

    public GUI(String title, int rows) {
        if (Bukkit.isPrimaryThread())
            inv = Bukkit.createInventory(this, 9 * rows, title);
        else {
            try {
                inv = Bukkit
                        .getScheduler()
                        .callSyncMethod(
                                Plugin.getInstance(),
                                () -> Bukkit.createInventory(GUI.this, 9 * rows, title))
                        .get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public GUI(String title) {
        this(title, 6);
    }


    public void clear() {
        inv.clear();
        runnableMap.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return inv;
    }

    public void addItem(int slot, ItemStack item, InventoryAction runnable) {
        inv.setItem(slot, item);
        runnableMap.put(slot, runnable);
    }

    public void removeItem(int slot) {
        inv.clear(slot);
        runnableMap.remove(slot);
    }



    public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent e) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        if (e.getClickedInventory() == null || e.getClickedInventory().getHolder() != this)
            return;
        InventoryAction action = runnableMap.get(e.getSlot());
        if (action == null)
            return;
        switch (e.getClick()) {
            case LEFT:
                action.click((Player) e.getWhoClicked());
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                action.rightClick((Player) e.getWhoClicked());
                break;
            case SHIFT_LEFT:
                action.shiftClick((Player) e.getWhoClicked());
                break;
        }
    }

    public static class InventoryAction {
        private final Consumer<Player> click, rightClick, shiftClick;

        public InventoryAction(Consumer<Player> click) {
            this(click, null, null);
        }

        public InventoryAction(Consumer<Player> click, Consumer<Player> rightClick, Consumer<Player> shiftClick) {
            this.click = click;
            this.rightClick = rightClick;
            this.shiftClick = shiftClick;
        }

        public void click(Player p) {
            click.accept(p);
        }

        public void rightClick(Player p) {
            if (rightClick != null) {
                rightClick.accept(p);
            }
        }

        public void shiftClick(Player p) {
            if (shiftClick != null) {
                shiftClick.accept(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```